# Fail form validation when select field value doesn't matches a pattern - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an html form that contains a select list field.
The first and default value of this field is "_none", all other values are numbers.
I want to fail to submission of the form and fire an html5 validation error when the value of this field is "_none". Unfortunately, the pattern attribute doesn't apply to select type fields.

any ideas?

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: HTML5 form validation using `required` _only_ works if the first option of the select has its value set to an empty string. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-required If you want to use a different value, then you have to implement validation yourself.